# Spectrum of periodically driven Floquet operator

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, many-body, floquet-theory

There is a periodically driven $XX$ model with alternating field. The piecewise Hamiltonian acts as following way

\begin{equation}
H_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{N-1}(\sigma^{x}_{i}\sigma^{x}_{i+1}+\sigma^{y}_{i}\sigma^{y}_{i+1})+\sum_{i}h_{i}\sigma^{z}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
H_2 = \sum_{i}h_{i}\sigma^{z}
\end{equation}
where, $h_i$ is the disorder field and $\sigma$'s are the Pauli spin-$1/2$ matrices. The dynamics take as
[
$H(t) =$
\begin{cases}
                                   H_1 & \text{if $0<\tau/2$} \\
                                   H_2 & \text{if $\tau/2<t<\tau$}. 
  \end{cases}
]
Here $\tau=2\pi/\omega$ is the time-period of the dynamics.  The Floquet operator of evolution is given by
$U=e^{-iH_2 \tau/2}e^{-i H_1 \tau/2}$.

Now, I am calculating the spectrum of $U(\tau)$ for different $\tau$. The eigenvalues of $U(\tau)$ are unit modulus and lie of a circle of unit radius. But for $\tau<0.4$, it is not the case and the circle is not clearly formed from the eigenvalue distributions. The circle is formed for $\tau \geq 0.4$. I am attaching resultw of my simulation. I don't understand this behavior. Any possible explanation of this behavior is most welcomed.   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the scale of the x-axis for the first figure.  The others look like subsets of the unit circle.  Notice that for very small $\tau$ the spectrum should be only some points on the unit circle near 1.